# Trying to implement a checkbox complete into To Do List

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, web-applications

Trying to implement a checkbox complete to my To Do List but unsure why it is not working. 
Whenever my code compiles down to Javascript I get this error:

"    ERROR in src/app/ToDo/todo.component.ts(89,32): error TS2339: Property 'item' does not exist on type 'ToDoComponent'. "

Also i'm unsure why my IDE is saying the task is considered an any statement.

**UPDATE:**

My console in my browser is displaying this error:

Unexpected closing tag "li". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ToDo, IToDo } from './todo.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../localStorageService';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IUser } from '../login/login.component';
import { ToastService } from '../toast/toast.service';


@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
  selector: 'todolist',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class ToDoComponent implements OnInit {
  [x: string]: any;
  todos: Array<IToDo> = [];
  inputtask = "";
  toDoParams = '';
  localStorageService: LocalStorageService<IToDo>;
  currentUser: IUser;
  @Output() update: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
    this.localStorageService = new LocalStorageService('todos');
  }



  private toastService: ToastService;
  async ngOnInit() {
    const currentUser = this.localStorageService.getItemsFromLocalStorage('user');
    console.log('from todos component', currentUser);
    if (currentUser == null) {
      await this.router.navigate(['login']);
    } else {
      // if user is logged in go and find any items from local storage and bind 
      // to the view
      const toDoItems = this.localStorageService.getItemsFromLocalStorage('todos');
      if (toDoItems && Array.isArray(toDoItems)) {
         this.todos = toDoItems;
      }
    }
  }






  addToDo(todo: string, cm?: boolean) {
    const td = {
      id: null,
      task: todo,
      completed: cm,
    }
    if (todo === '') {
      alert('You must enter in a task TO DO!')
    } else {
      this.todos.push(td);
    }
    this.saveItemsToLocalStorage(this.todos);
  }

  delete(index: number) {
    this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("index", index);
    this.saveItemsToLocalStorage(this.todos);
  }

  clear() {
    this.todos = [];
    console.log('index', this.todos)
    this.saveItemsToLocalStorage(this.todos);
  }

  getItemsFromLocalStorage(key: string) {
    const savedToDo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    console.log('from getItemsFromLocalStorage savedItems', savedToDo);
    return this.localStorageService.getItemsFromLocalStorage(key);
    return savedToDo;
  }

completeItem() {
  this.update.emit({
    task: this.todos,
    changes: {completed: this.task.completed}
  });
}

  saveItemsToLocalStorage(todos: Array<IToDo>) {
    todos = this.sortByID(todos);
    return this.localStorageService.saveItemsToLocalStorage(todos);

    const savedToDo = localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    console.log('from saveItemsToLocalStorage savedToDos: ', savedToDo);
    return savedToDo;
  }

  sortByID(todos: Array<IToDo>) {
    todos.sort((prevToDo: IToDo, presToDo: IToDo) => {

      return prevToDo.id > presToDo.id ? 1 : -1;
    });
    console.log('the sorted ToDos', this.todos);
    return this.todos;
  }



  logout() {
    // clear localStorage
    this.localStorageService.clearItemFromLocalStorage('user');
    // navigate to login page
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index"
        class="list-group-item shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded border border-dark rounded" id="myTask">
        <div class="todo-item">
            {{todo.task}} <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delete()">X</button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="todo-checkbox" (click)="completeItem()">
            <span class="todo-title" [ngClass]="{'todo-complete': item.completed}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="todo-title" [ngClass]="{'todo-complete': item.completed}">
```

Here you are using `item` which doesn't exist in your typescript file. Did you mean to use `todo` from your `*ngFor` ?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but that didn't really do much, my code is still broken.